# Add text to input field using text hyperlink

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

This will be probably dummy question but I cannot find solution for that.

We have piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.tags_select a').click(function() {
                var value = $(this).text();
                var input = $('#text_tag_input');
                input.val(input.val() + value + ', ');
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

and HTML:

```
<input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />

<div class="tags_select">
<a href="#">text1</a>
<a href="#">text2</a>
<a href="#">text3</a>
</div>
```

the issue is following - when I click on link text1, and then text2 etc. everything appears in input. What I want to achieve is to display only one variable (in this case, newest, last cliked).

thanks!

Comment: It's simple... clear the input on every click :) something like input.val('') before you add the value if you still want to keep your code ;)

Comment: The line `input.val(input.val() + value + ', ');` literally says "set the value of the input to be the current input value, plus the value that was clicked." It's doing what you told it to.

Comment: Or simply `input.val(value)`

Comment: it was so simple.. thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.tags_select a').click(function() {
            $('#text_tag_input').val("");
            var value = $(this).text();
            var input = $('#text_tag_input').val(value);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />
<div class="tags_select">
  <a href="#">text1</a>
  <a href="#">text2</a>
  <a href="#">text3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
input.val(value);
```

instead of:

```
input.val(input.val() + value + ', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input.val(input.val() + value + ', ')
```

What that does is set the value of your input = (input's current value + clicked value + ',')

```
input.val(value)
```

The code above simply sets the input value to the clicked value.

---

However, if you do not wish to remove anything in your code, you can just add

`input.val('')` before you call `input.val(input.val() + value + ', ')`.